# SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER works strange

Tags: mysql

I tried

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER
```

and it shows me:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'test_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'pass'
```

but this user has grants for select for `test_script` database.

Here is show grants by root:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR test_user

GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'test_user'@'%'
GRANT SELECT ON `test_script`.* TO 'test_user'@'%'
```

Why SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER doesn't show me grants for test_script table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks to be because `CURRENT_USER` (the logged-in user) is `'test_user'@'localhost'`, who has different grants from `'test_user'@'%'`.

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'test_user'@'%'
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'test_user'@'localhost'
```

If you login via TCP with `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u test_user -p`, you should now be using the `'test_user'@'%'` grants.

When you execute a `SHOW GRANTS` statement for a username alone, *without* specifying the host, MySQL will attempt to list grants for the user `@'%'`. If that specification didn't exist at all, you would get

```
ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'test_user' on host '%'
```

In your case, that specification existed, but with different grants than the `test_user@localhost`.